# The background cache eviction process was unable to free [10] percent of the cache for context

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, caching, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy spring boot application on my server. I have kept my WAR file on webapps folder inside Tomcat.

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.privilance</groupId>
<artifactId>privilance_survey</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>privilance_survey</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--     
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.21</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>privilance</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I did some search and find out some people solved their problem by adding this bean.

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            final int cacheSize = 40 * 1024;
            StandardRoot standardRoot = new StandardRoot(context);
            standardRoot.setCacheMaxSize(cacheSize);
            context.setResources(standardRoot); // This is what made it work in my case.

            logger.info(String.format("New cache size (KB): %d", context.getResources().getCacheMaxSize()));
        }
    };
    return tomcatFactory;
}
```

But in my case this is also not working. Whenever I run `localhost:8080/privilance` on my browser says:

> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target
>   resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

and in my cmd prompt says:

> the background cache eviction process was unable to free [10] percent
>   of the cache for context. consider increasing maximum size of the
>   cache ....approximately [9285] kb of data remained on the cache.

Comment: Not related to the question, but the current version of PDFBox is 2.0.5, not 2.0.0.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple solutions:

- Increase cache (recommended)
- Lower the TTL (not recommended)
- Suppress cache log warnings (not recommended)
- Disable cache

more details on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893297/tomcat-8-throwing-org-apache-catalina-webresources-cache-getresource-unable-to)

Answer (score 0):

What you get in the cmd is probably warning ? I think this might be something to with the resouce configuration in web.xml. Please see [Running servlet shows error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061147/running-servlet-shows-error). Hope it helps.

Comment: i am using spring boot and i don't have web.xml